# Using linear regression with binary and categorical variables.

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, regression

I have a dataset with a binary variable: "Religious" with $0$ being "no" and $1$ being "yes". And a categorical variable "Contraceptive" having the values $1,2$ and $3$. Where $1$ = no use, $2$ = short term use and $3$ = long term use. The original dataset is something like this:

\begin{align}
&\text{Religious}\:\:\: \text{Contraceptive}\\
&1 \hspace{42pt} 1  \\
&1 \hspace{42pt} 1  \\
&0 \hspace{42pt} 2 \\
&0 \hspace{42pt} 3 \\
&\vdots
\end{align}

then I created three other columns and changed the contraceptive column to:

\begin{align}
&\text{no use} \:\:\: \text{short} \:\:\: \text{long}\\ 
&1 \hspace{28pt} 0 \hspace{28pt} 0 \\
&1 \hspace{28pt} 0 \hspace{28pt} 0 \\
&0 \hspace{28pt} 1 \hspace{28pt} 0\\
&0 \hspace{28pt} 0 \hspace{28pt} 1\\
&\vdots
\end{align}

Is now possible to use a simple linear regression with these variables? How does one do that? I'm using R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Your dependent variable is binary, i.e., $\{0,1\}$, hence a possible model is a logistic regression, i.e., 
$$
\widehat{ \mathbb{P}( Y_i = 1) } = \frac{1}
{ 1 + \exp\{ -(\beta_0 + \beta_1\text{short} 
+ 
\beta_1 \text{short} )
\}},
$$
in R

`glm( formula = Religious ~ short + long,
          family = binomial(link = "logit") )`

Comment: What if the dependent variable is Contraceptive. I want to check how the religion impacts on the method of use in the contraceptive.

Comment: Then multinomial logistic regression https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression

Comment: If I had a categorical (contraceptive) with a numerical (age) then can I use a linear regression? What type of variables can I use linear regression, when the dependent variable is a categorical one (contraceptive) ? Maybe something like this exists in multiple linear regression, lm(short+long+noUse ~ age)

Comment: Then you can use a multivariate regression. E.g., http://users.stat.umn.edu/~helwig/notes/mvlr-Notes.pdf slide 43 and on